# How to force a software's splash screen to the back

Tags: linux-mint, window-management

I am having an issue with a software that I launch via SSH on Linux Mint. As I run the command to launch it, its splash screen appears and stays on top of every other opened window, across all workspaces, as long as the software is not fully loaded, which sometimes takes a few minutes.

I did not manage to put this splash screen behind the other windows and I could not find any solution. Any ideas ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

1. `wmctrl` : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl or
2. if you have KDE it has a very powerful DM which can change pretty much all windows attributes: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/windowspecific/windowspecific.pdf
3. or even `man kdocker` which allows to minimize to systray all applications

Comment: Thank your for your anwser. I use Cinnamon. I have tested Kdocker, which tells me that the window I try to minimize is not a normal window. It still manages to minimize it, but the software seems to freeze.

Comment: You said earlier it takes ages to start it - it's unlikely that KDocker might make it freeze.

Comment: I had waited half an hour, so I thought it would have frozen. I tested once more without kdocker and I also had a similar issue, so it's not Kdocker's fault. I finally got it to work with Kdocker once, so I'll accept your answer !